# List pointing behavior python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I need some help to understand better how list in python internally deal with the objects to it points to.

I will explain my doubt with situation case. Well, here we go.

Let's imagine that I created a class called Foo a I put some of its instances in a list, like the following:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__():
    ...
    ...

foo1 = FOO()
foo2 = FOO()
l = [foo1,foo2]
```

From my understanding, que list is pointing to the instance objects foo1 and foo2. I want to mean with this is that any change that I perform directly in the instances objects will be done in the list and vice-versa, which is totally expected since the list and the variables foo1 and foo2 are pointing to the same instance objects. This is great, and implies that I could perform changes in this instances objects in this way:

```
for foo in l:   
  perform_some_changes(foo)

eval(foo1); eval(foo2); eval(l[0]); eval(l[1])
```

With the eval() function I would see that the changes performed in the for loop persisted in the variables and list. Again, everything as expected.

Given the foregoing, my question is: Why, if instead of use an instance object created by the user, I used an int() of float() build-in data type that are also objects (since, everything in python is object), the list would not maintain the same behavior? Again, I will explain what I mean with same codes:

```
a = 0
b = 0
l = [a,b]
for el in l:
  for i in range(5):
    el+=1
print a # zero
print b # zero
print l # zero
```

In the situation show above, the changes performed in the for loop would not persist in the variables and list. Nevertheless, this does note make sense for me because of what were just discussed. For me, the changes performed in the loop should persist in the variables and list, sinse everything is should be pointing to the same address. Am I missing some thing? Is so, in the case, how could I make everything points to the same address and not create new instances.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Because  `+=` is a rebinding operation, not a mutation.

Comment: Specifically, the behavior of `el+=1` depends on the implementation of `type(el).__iadd__`

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking that the list is referencing variables `a` and `b`, and following this assumption, then if you change `a`, you should see it changed inside the list too. But this is not true in Python, where variable names are "just" names; the objects themselves are referenced in that list. So yes, if you *alter* an object then the altered object will be reflected, but if you bind the name to a new object, this doesn't reflect on the list because the list has a reference to the original object, not to the variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python there are **mutable** and **immutable** data types (this list is not necessarily complete):

- **mutable:**

  - `list`s
  - `dict`ionaries
  - `set`s
  - custom `object`s
- **immutable:**

  - basic numeric data types like `int`, `float`, `bool`, `long`, `complex`
  - `str`ings
  - `tuple`s
  - `frozenset`s

Now **mutable** types are similar to **reference data types** stored on the heap in other languages whereas **immutable** types are more like **value data types** directly stored on the stack memory.

You can manipulate instances of **mutable** data types. All variable names that referenced the old object still reference the new object because it's the same instance.

In contrast, you can not manipulate **immutable** data types. When you perform any operations that *seem* to manipulate them, they do return a new modified copy of the instance. The original instance stays untouched and is still referenced by all variable names that pointed to it before. However the new, modified instance is only referenced by the variable name you assigned it to. It is no longer related to the old instance.

---

**To sum up:**

You can modify **mutable** objects in-place and all references to them will reflect the changes.

**Immutable** data types may not be modified, you will always get a new instance when you try it. All other references will stay bound to the old instance and are unaffected by the "manipulations".

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in Python are immutable, so += operation creates new int object and makes list element reference to it, while variables reference to old objects.